# DRF: django rest framework case insensitive lookup in detail view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

How to make urls case insensitive with certain parameters passed

For example, assuming Stock model has a ticker. All links below should find the same ticker content, right now they are case sensitive and try to search for different values:

- /stocks/AAPL
- /stocks/aapl
- /stocks/AaPl

views.py

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    lookup_field = "ticker"

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"], url_path="is", url_name="is")
    def get_income_statement(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        is_qs = IncomeStatement.objects.filter(ticker=self.get_object())
        serializer = IncomeStatementSerializer(is_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"], url_path="bs", url_name="bs")
    def get_balance_sheet(self, requests, *args, **kwargs):
        bs_qs = BalanceSheet.objects.filter(ticker=self.get_object())
        serializer = BalanceSheetSerializer(bs_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @action(detail=True, methods=["get"], url_path="cf", url_name="cf")
    def get_cashflows_statement(self, requests, *args, **kwargs):
        cf_qs = CashflowsStatement.objects.filter(self.get_object())
        serializer = CashflowsStatementSerializer(cf_qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)


class IncomeStatementDetail(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = IncomeStatement.objects.all()
    serializer_field = IncomeStatementSerializer


class BalanceSheetDetail(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BalanceSheet.objects.all()
    serializer_field = BalanceSheetSerializer


class CashflowsStatementDetail(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CashflowsStatement.objects.all()
    serializer_field = CashflowsStatementSerializer
```

urls.py

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r"stocks", views.StockViewSet)
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

models.py

```
class Stock(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        value = self.ticker
        self.slug = slugify(value, allow_unicode=True)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.ticker

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "stock"
        verbose_name_plural = "stocks"
        ordering = ["ticker"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`lookup_url_kwarg`** and **`lookup_field`** as

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'ticker'
    lookup_field = 'ticker__iexact'
    # rest of your code
```

You can refer the [source code of **`get_object(self)`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/374c0d414237708a28eccc412c078c06d0d82be2/rest_framework/generics.py#L75) to see how DRF fetching the ***model object*** in the detail view.